# send_static_file not picking up from static folder at root in Blueprint

Tags: python, flask, static-files, blueprint

From the `views.py` inside my blueprint, im trying to use the `send_static_file` to deliver an `index.html` and just cant get it to work

I have a blueprint called main which I initialize as such in the `__init__.py` under the blueprint folder `mod_main`

```
from flask import Blueprint 
mod_main = Blueprint('main',name,static_folder='/static', static_url_path='/static') 
from . import views
```

In my main `app` initialization in the `__init__.py` under the root `app` folder

```
app = Flask(__name__)
from .mod_main import mod_main as main_blueprint
app.register_blueprint(main_blueprint,url_prefix='/main')
```

Under the `views.py` file in the blueprint main (`mod_main` folder)

```
@mod_main.route('/')
def index():
    return mod_main.send_static_file('index.html')
```

But it keeps resolving to `404 Not found`. Any clue how i can serve the `index.html` that is under the `static` folder in the root `app` folder (I can get it to work if i create a static folder inside the blueprint. But i would like to deliver it from the root `app`)

Heres the structure with the essential files

```
app
|
-- mod_main/
   |
    -- views.py
    -- __init__.py

-- __init__.py

-- static /
   |
    -- index.html
```

Comment: Are you sure `index` is being called? What does `mod_main/__init__.py` look like?

Comment: dirn, this is how the mod_main/__init__.py looks like 

  from flask import Blueprint

  mod_main = Blueprint('main',__name__,static_folder='/static', static_url_path='/static')

  from . import views

Comment: It's better to put that in your original post so it can be formatted correctly. Also, is `form` just a typo or is that how it appears in your code?

Comment: done. no the form was just a typo when i typed it in here :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've told the blueprint to find the static files in `/static`, or, a folder called `static` in the root of your file system. Assuming you don't want to change it to `static` and move the folder into `mod_main`, there are a couple of different approaches you can take.

If you want to make the distinction between static files for the app and static files for the blueprint, you can serve the file through the current app.

```
# mod_main/views.py
from flask import current_app

from . import mod_main


@mod_main.route('/')
def index():
    return current_app.send_static_file('index.html')
```

If, however, you intend to use the existing `static` as your only static folder, you need to update your blueprint to use this folder.

```
# mod_main/__init__.py
import os

from flask import Blueprint

static_folder = os.path.join(os.pardir, 'static')
mod_main = Blueprint(
    'main', __name__, static_folder=static_folder, static_url_path='/static')

from . import views
```

Comment: I was trying to use this example to send the static files from the current blueprint. for those interested in that do: your_blueprint_object.send_static_file